# I'm facing a n error when throwing a BadRequestException which is not supposed to happen

Tags: asynchronous, exception, async-await, nestjs

I am writing a basic signup api and using find() function to check if there are any duplicate api and in an if() condition im throwing a BadRequestException but it is giving me an error if the input email is already in use. A very similar code in another project is not giving any error but this is.

This is the code snippet. when given an email id already registered in the database it is supposed to throw an exception.

```
import { Injectable, BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { randomBytes, scrypt as _scrypt } from 'crypto';
import { promisify } from 'util';

const scrypt = promisify(_scrypt);

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) {}

  async signup(ogname: string,
    email: string,
    password: string,
    phone: string,
    date_of_birth: Date,
    type: string,) {
    // See if email is in use
    const name = null;
    const users = await this.usersService.find(name, email);
    console.log(users.length);
    if (users.length) {
      throw new BadRequestException('email in use');
    }

    // Hash the users password
    // Generate a salt
    const salt = randomBytes(8).toString('hex');

    // Hash the salt and the password together
    const hash = (await scrypt(password, salt, 32)) as Buffer;

    // Join the hashed result and the salt together
    const result = salt + '.' + hash.toString('hex');

    //Create a new user and save it
    const user = await this.usersService.create(ogname, email, result, phone, date_of_birth, type)

    // return the user
    return user;
  }

  signin() {}
}
```

expected result:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": "email in use",
    "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

[Unexpected result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytKtc.png)

here is the github link for the entire code:
https://github.com/chaitanya2108/appaya_basketball_club

Answer (score 0):

I've just read the code you posted on GitHub, it's quite different than the code you posted here, then I cannot reproduce the issue.

However, I can give you some suggestion for better implementations:

- Try the Unique decorator: https://typeorm.io/decorator-reference#column
- Use try-catch in asynchronous in order to handle error when signing up.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I have updated my code on GitHub and everything is as it is in the question posted here. please do look into it

Comment: pleaes add me to your github project, I will create a PR. my username is peterburgs